# Как обновлять Image используя MVVM паттерн

Tags: c#, изображения, mvvm

После создания фотографии отображается фото на интерфейс, первая фотография отображается, но после создания новой, возникает ошибка:

> The process cannot access the file '...tmp\Photo.jpeg' because it is being used by another process.

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '...tmp\Photo.jpeg' because it is being used by another process.
> at System.IO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath)
> at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
> at PhotoMerge.ViewModel.MainViewModel.CreatePhoto(Int32 channel, Camera camera) ...\ViewModel\MainViewModel.cs

Model:

```
public class Camera : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private string _address;
   private string _login;
   private string _password;
   private string _name;
   private string _path;
   private Uri? _imagePath;

   public string Address { get { return _address; } }
   public string Login { get { return _login; } }
   public string Password { get { return _password; } }
   public string Name { get { return _name; } }
   public string Path { get { return _path; } }

   public Uri? ImagePath
   {
      get { return _imagePath; }

      set
      {
         _imagePath = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
      }
   }

   public Camera(string address, string login, string password, string name, string path)
   {
      _address = address;
      _login = login;
      _password = password;
      _name = name;
      _path = path; 
   }

   public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Camera camera;
   private ICommand createPhoto;

   public Camera Camera
   {
      get { return this.camera; }
   }

   public ICommand CreatePhoto
   {
      get { return this.createPhoto; }
   }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      camera = new Camera("192.168.3.103", "admin", "1", "Photo", @"C:\tmp\");
      createPhoto = new DelegateCommand(parameter => CreateTestPhoto(1, camera));
   }

   private void CreateTestPhoto(int channel, Camera camera)
   {
      if (File.Exists(camera.Path + camera.Name + ".jpeg"))
         File.Delete(camera.Path + camera.Name + ".jpeg");

      if (HiWatch.Create(channel, camera.Login, camera.Password, camera.Path, camera.Name, 550))
      {
         BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
         bitmap.BeginInit();
         bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(camera.Path + camera.Name + ".jpeg", UriKind.Absolute);
         bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
         bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
         bitmap.EndInit();

         camera.ImagePath = bitmap.UriSource;
      }
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Camera.ImagePath}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Uniform" MinWidth="364" MinHeight="205" />
```

Как правильно реализовать обновление фото в UI?

Comment: Ну так вы создаете правильно BitmapImage с учетом BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad, а потом все это выбрасываете и достаете из него только Uri, который и передаете контролу. Конечно контрол захватывает файл и не дает его удалить. Вы должны в Source передать этот ваш bitmap. В MVVM подходе вы можете добавить конвертер к {Binding Camera.ImagePath} и не использовать во вьюмоделях никаких изображений, где им не место

Comment: Замечу, что у вас есть небольшое нарушение MVVM, ибо `CreateTestPhoto` - это метод модели, в VM вы должны только дергать этот метод, и на его основе делать что-то. Ну и прямая привязка к модели, подумайте, может стоит создать событие оповещающее о том, что модель изменилась и на его основе создавать/обновлять VM, в которому уже и привязывается окно.

Comment: @vitidev я пробовал реализовать в Camera переменную класса ImageSource и передавать его в контрол, например: camera.ImageSource = bitmap, но отображение фото не происходило

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не могли вы бы указать какой-нибудь пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и ещё подскажите, если у меня имеется ObservableCollection с камерами, и мне необходимо реализовать метод работы в котором используется несколько камер, где его правильней реализовать?

Comment: Пример не дам, просто разделите задачу на части, где одна часть это UI, а другая часть ваши данные и работа с ними, обе они не знают ничего друг про друга, а вот чтоб они могли взаимодействовать, есть промежуточный слой, который берет данные, и отдает их UI, аналогично и в обратную сторону. Что касается `ObservableCollection`, то тут все зависит от того, что там. Камера - это устройство, а устройство это модель, все методы управления камерами должны быть там, VM только дергает эти методы и получает результат, не более.

Comment: Значит [не так пробовали](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.source). С MVVM просто: модель - логика, вьюмодель - "что рисовать", а вид - "как рисовать", Вьюмодель держит стейт для вида. Она знает о камерах, о текущей камере и т.п., но не знает ни про какой BitmapImage/Image, даже опосредованно. Вид смотрит на вьюмодель и рисует что-то по её состоянию. `new BitmapImage()` должен быть или в code-behind (вид), или  в конвертере(вид) или проходить транзитом от модели (но во вьюмоделях не должно быть никакой зависимости на System.Windows)

Comment: @vitidev добавил в Camera метод, который делает фото  и уведомляет, что ImageSouce обновлен. Команду изменил на: createPhoto = new DelegateCommand(parameter => camera.CreatePhoto());  Заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ имеете ввиду создать event Action Update в модели, и создать событие в ViewModel, если Update изменился?

Comment: @AndreyFerzh Модели должны быть всегда независимыми от чего либо, они не должны знать про другие слои. Представьте, что у вас модель камеры лежит в другом проекте, там есть метод "сделать снимок", вот как вы узнаете, что снимок был сделан? Варианта у вас 2, либо этот метод будет что-то возвращать, либо этот метод вызовет событие, слушатели которого узнают о том, что было сделано фото. Что использовать - зависит от цели, поставленных задач. Тут выбирайте самостоятельно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом:

Model:

```
public class Camera : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private string _address;
   private string _login;
   private string _password;
   private string _name;
   private string _path;
   private BitmapImage? _bitmapImage;

   public event Action PhotoCreated;

   public string Address { get => _address; }
   public string Login { get => _login; }
   public string Password { get => _password; }
   public string Name { get => _name; }
   public string Path { get => _path; }

   public BitmapImage? BitmapImage
   {
      get => _bitmapImage;
      set
      {
         _bitmapImage = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("BitmapImage");
      }
   }

   public Camera(string address, string login, string password, string name, string path)
   {
      _address = address;
      _login = login;
      _password = password;
      _name = name;
      _path = path; 
   }

   public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
   }

   public void CreatePhoto()
   {
      if (File.Exists(_path + _name  + ".jpeg"))
         File.Delete(_path  + _name  + ".jpeg");

      if (HiWatch.Create(_login, _password, _path, _name))
      {
         BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
         bitmap.BeginInit();
         bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(_path + _name + ".jpeg", UriKind.Absolute);
         bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
         bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
         bitmap.EndInit();

         _bitmapImage = bitmap;
         PhotoCreated?.Invoke();
      }
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private Camera camera;
   private ImageSource image;
   private ICommand createPhoto;

   public Camera Camera
   {
      get => camera;
   }

   public ImageSource Image
   {
       get => image;
       set
       {
          image = value;
          image.Freeze();
          OnPropertyChanged("Image");
       }
   }

   public ICommand CreatePhoto
   {
      get { return this.createPhoto; }
   }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      camera = new Camera("192.168.3.103", "admin", "1", "Photo", @"C:\tmp\");
      createPhoto = new DelegateCommand(parameter => camera.CreatePhoto()));
      camera.PhotoCreated += PhotoUpdate;
   }

   private void PhotoUpdate()
   {
      Image = camera.BitmapImage;
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Uniform" />
```

Comment: Вы делаете прямую привязку к модели, минуя VM слой, это не есть хорошо. Вот смотрите, когда вы нажимаете на реальном фотоаппарате кнопку, что вы ожидаете? Наверно то, что он вам сделает фото и выдаст ее вам куда либо (флешка, сразу проявит ее, и так далее). Другими словами, если переводить это в язык программирования, когда вызывается `camera.CreatePhoto()` ожидается то, что метод вернет нам сделанную фотку, а не сохранит гдет там в своих недрах. Пусть он возвращает тот-же `Bitmap`, а уже в VM слое, вы для него делаете `ImageSource` для привязки.

Comment: Ну а сам возврат, логично тут будет возврат самого метода, но как я и говорил ранее, можно и событием, только тогда метод стоит переименовать в что-то, что будет говорить об этом. Сейчас ваша модель отвечает не за свою задачу, ибо `ImageSource` нужен по сути только для привязки, но это у вас почему-то делает модель. Разбивайте все, не ленитесь, MVVM именно про это.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправил, но верно ли я вас понял?) Если нет, то поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Представьте что у вас отдельная сборка с вьюмоделями. Так вот у этой сборки не должно быть зависимостей от System.Windows. Так вы будете знать чего не должно быть во вьюмоделях. То есть никаких ImageSource Image и битмапов. Ваша вьюмодель должна выставить наружу необходимую инфу, а уж потом ее превратит в отображаемую картинку сам вид с помощью конвертера или code-behind, хоть банальное `<Image Source="{Binding ImageFilePath, Converter={.... PathToImageConverter}"

Comment: @AndreyFerzh Да, вполне, модель теперь как видите не отвечает за лишние действия, а просто делает то, что и должна. Только подумайте над переименованием `CreatePhoto`, ибо логично предположить, что он должен что-то вернуть (а-ля `var photo = ... CreatePhoto();`), а он этого не делает, что не соответствует его названию. Про ViewModel в принципе совет выше тоже уместен, `ImageSource` это на уровне шрифтов, цветов, и так далее, а все это относится к UI, то есть View слою. Но ИМХО, MVVM это рекомендации, а не требования, не вижу ничего плохого хранить простой `ImageSource` в VM)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Это сродни "зачем нам ORM, мы не будем менять базу данных". Вьюмодель должна иметь возможность использоваться без переписывания там, где не существует WPF. Конечно WPF проекты крайне редко становятся кроссплатформой, но все же эта рекомендация (не иметь зависимости на сборки вида) довольно просто выполняется.

Comment: @vitidev Я не спорю, но как вы и сказали верно, WPF это всеж Windows проект, а если проект заточен исключительно под Windows, то смысл в написании конверторов и других абстракций попросту пропадает. Шрифты, цвета, и прочее, еще да, согласен, ибо это все спокойно пишется в XAML, но картинка, а точней ее источник, тут уж зависит от проекта.